# How to disable auto brightness adjustment in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, brightness

Everytime most elements in my screen are white, brightness goes up. Then, some black elements appear and the screen's brightness goes down. How can I permanently disable this annoying behaviour?

I have searched all settings with no luck.

Comment: turn off HDR in your monitor's settings.

Comment: I am using a laptop

Comment: wayland or xorg? Can you paste output from `inxi -G`?

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` / `Power` / `Automatic Screen Brightness`

Comment: I don't have this option.

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 23.04. Brightness is constantly auto-adjusting which is _extremely_ annoying, and there is no option to turn off this behavior in settings. Calling `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false` does, indeed, change the setting but automatic brightness adjustments continue ((